# How can I customize the Log Out in Laravel 8 using Breeze?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, logout, laravel-breeze

I'm using tailwind, Laravel 8 and Breeze.
After installing Breeze I would like to customize (change size, color and text) the log out button but I have no idea how to do that.

Here is the code :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">

                        @csrf

    <x-dropdown-link :href="route('logout')"
           onclick="event.preventDefault();
     .closest('form').submit();">
     {{ __('Log Out') }}
     </x-dropdown-link>
</form>
```

and the auth.php

```
Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
            ->middleware('auth')
            ->name('logout');
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, you should be aware that the `dropdown-link` is rendered using a component. When you alter the components, it may affect all pages that use that component.

You can modify that component in this file: 
`resources/views/components/dropdown-link.blade.php`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your blade file

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
```

@csrf

its on working